# Blender is very slow in Pose Mode but only with one character?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigify, pose-mode

first sorry for my english, I will try to be as clear as possible.

Recently I try to make a rigg in blender, everything was ok but now I'm doing the skinning and when I move the character in pose mode (to test the skinning) the selection of controller and move is really slow.

I downloaded many character and animate it, and I don't have the same issue of "slow pose-mode" with them.

So i searched everywhere on the internet and read all forums I can find but I didn't find solutions... I re-started my rigg twice and looked closely at my bones, the relations between bones, the IK-FK constrains ... But I didn't find any problem so I don't now where the problem come.

I don't know if it will help you but I use two addons : "Rigify" and "Bones layers Managers".

If you have any idea, or if you want more detail, I'm listening to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally found the problem,the model was too heavy in poly (yes I know, this is a really stupid mistake, but I didn't think about that, you can laugh ;) ). I decimate it, bind and skin, and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Turn of all *Subdivision* modifiers in the viewport but not for rendering.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)